CHSH rigidity for sharing mixed state
In the CHSH game the best winning rate $\omega^{*}=\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{4}$ and if the players achieve the winning rate of $\omega^{*}-\epsilon$ by sharing a pure two-qubit state $|\psi\rangle$,then the rigidity shows that there exists unitary $U,V$such that $||(U\otimes V)|\psi\rangle-|EPR\rangle||\leq O(\sqrt{\epsilon})$. Is there the rigidity result for sharing mixed states? That is if they achieve wining rate $\omega^{*}-\epsilon$ by sharing two-qubit mixed state $\psi$, do we have upper bound for $\min_{U,V}||(U\otimes V)\psi(U\otimes V)^{\dagger}-|EPR\rangle\langle EPR||_2$?
If $\psi=\sum_i\lambda_i|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$, and the winning rate sharing $|\psi_i\rangle$ is $\omega^{*}-\epsilon_i$, then there exists $U_i$ and $V_i$, such that $||(U_i\otimes V_i)|\psi_i\rangle-|EPR\rangle||\leq O(\sqrt{\epsilon_i})$, the problem here is these $\{U_i\otimes V_i\}$ can be different for different $|\psi_i\rangle$.

There is a rigidity theorem for mixed states that applies to CHSH, see Lemma 4.12 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2310.12662. The idea is to work with the purification. That being said, I am not certain how it can be applied to bound the quantity in question.

A proof sketch idea that might work: we argue via convexity that achieving the optimal winning rate is only possible if each $|\psi_i\rangle$ are shared states in some optimal strategy. Then show that if it achieves the optimal rate, then all $|\psi_i\rangle$ must be the same state. You may need to use the fact that the measurement operators cannot depend on $i$.
